# Getting Response Data after sending http get (python requests)

Tags: python, session, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm attempting to parse response data from a requests Session object after sending a get requests. I cannot send another get requests from the same Session object without losing its particular session data. The session data cannot be lost or parsing it is pointless for my application.

```
session = Session()
session.get(url)
getSoup(session) 

def getSoup(session):
     soup = BeautifulSoup(#sessiondatahere, "html.parser")
     return soup
```

Comment: to save the response of the data have you  tried appending results to the list or dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

As with anything in Python, when you call a method you need to do something with the response. Here, the response comes from calling the `get` method. So:

```
response = session.get(url)
soup = getSoup(response.text)
```